# How can I get the score of the underlying matching query in a bool query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very complex search, where I am essentially performing a large search for articles that match at least one entity in a group of many entities.

What I noticed is that as I add more entities, the scores dramatically change because my `should` clause grows in size.

Here's an example of my query with 2 entities:

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "track_scores": true,
  "min_score": 0.05,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "boost_factor": 1000000
                    }
                  ],
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "relatedProfiles": [
                        "SomethingElse/124026966662",
                        "SomeLocation/707765"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "boost_mode": "replace"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "query": "Generic Systems",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "fields": [
                          "content.title",
                          "content.description"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "query": "Generic Systems, Inc.",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "fields": [
                          "content.title",
                          "content.description"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": "1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "_name": "0e7da739-1d18-448b-caa2-5c615a59d108"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "function_score": {
                  "functions": [
                    {
                      "boost_factor": 1000000
                    }
                  ],
                  "query": {
                    "terms": {
                      "relatedProfiles": [
                        "SomeLocation/162479",
                        "SomethingElse/32b95cc3-a363-47c3-2ac1-86fdb3b7d108"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "boost_mode": "replace"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "query": "SomeBusiness Computer Inc",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "fields": [
                          "content.title",
                          "content.description"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "type": "phrase",
                        "query": "SomeBusiness, Inc",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "fields": [
                          "content.title",
                          "content.description"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": "1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "_name": "00cc4b36-ce6b-4816-e61e-b7124344d108"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "type": "News"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "language": [
                          "eng"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "type": [
                    "Social",
                    "Job",
                    "Unknown"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "lt": "2015-05-13T09:25:40.605",
              "gt": "2013-05-13T09:25:40.605"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the underlying match to be the score? Or, at the least, the score of the section below the name query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe https://elastic.co/webinars/elasticsearch-query-dsl has some insights; later in the video he talks about the *Dis Max Query*.

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html

> "We want the primary score to be the one associated with the highest boost, not the sum of the field scores (as Boolean Query would give)."

Comment: It was the Dis Max query after all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explain API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-explain.html) for this. ON providing the query , it gives you a lot of information per document match on how that score was deduced. Its the perfect tool for debugging scores.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not looking to debug the score, but rather to not have the presence of one entity in the query to affect the scores of other entities.

Comment: Maybe https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elasticsearch-query-dsl has some insights; later in the video he talks about the *Dis Max Query": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html "We want the primary score to be the one associated with the highest boost, not the sum of the field scores (as Boolean Query would give)." Or maybe the "Constant Score Query": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html But TBH giving your description I'm not sure what your real goal is.

Comment: @mark, can you make that an answer instead of a comment that way I can accept it? Your Dis Max Query advice was spot on!